# C# File upload- original creation date overridden

Tags: c#

I have a MVC web application, which provides users to upload text files.  I then take those text files and store it on a folder which is monitored by a file system watcher and in turn upon newly generated files, it transfers those files to an FTP server. Everything works great but there is a small issue with File Creation Dates. I noticed that when they upload the file to my web application, the original file creation date is replaced by the current date (the time when the file is actually uploaded). This does not happen on my local machine. Before I save the file I even try to get the file creation date but its always wrong. Could it be a server configuartion setting?   My requirement is to take the original file creation date and convert that to an epoch date in milliseconds.  Again, locally on dev machine it works great, just on the server it overrides the original creation date. Below is my code:

```
 string storedFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}.out", destinationPath, System.Guid.NewGuid());
                            file.ElementAt(1).SaveAs(storedFileName);

                            DateTime fileCreatedDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file.ElementAt(1).FileName);

                            //Change Creation DateTime to Epoch
                            TimeSpan span = (fileCreatedDate - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime());
                            double epoch = span.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

There is no metadata about file included as part of HTTP file upload. The most you can get is file name, sometimes path.

If you need to obtain other file information you need to create some sort of client application to perform custom upload. The browser alone will not provide your script with such information either.

Comment: Oh yes, on the local machine,  it does return the meta data for instance file creation date. I just debugged and its looks like october 24 2012, on the server this date is always the current date